# yii include php file by ajax .. php have yii form

Tags: php, yii

i have yii form with ajax submit button i want to include this form at my home page when i click at button  i write my code like :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: x,
        url:'<?php echo yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("site/info_form");?>',
        scriptCharset:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(get)
        {
        document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML=get;

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

info_form   get form with ajax submit button .. when click submit it can't do ajax

my controller :

public function actionAdd_main_info()
    {

```
    $model_info=new FreeMainInfo;
    $user=Yii::app()->session['user_id'] ;



     if(isset($_POST['FreeMainInfo']))   
{
    $model_info->attributes=$_POST['FreeMainInfo'];
    if($model_info->validate())
    {
      $model_info->full=1;
      $model_info->reg_id=$user;

      $model_info->save(false);
      echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'success' ));
      Yii::app()->end();

    }
     else
     {
      $error = CActiveForm::validate($model_info);
      if($error!='[]')
      echo $error;
      Yii::app()->end();
      }


}
}
```

my form which i generate by ajax :

```
                                <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'main_info',
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//site/add_main_info'),
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => false,
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal SearchForm'),
)); ?>
```

my ajax submit button:

```
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save Your Main Info',CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/add_main_info','render'=>true)),
                                 array(
                                         'type'=>'POST',
                                         'dataType'=>'json',
                                         'data'=>'js:$("#main_info").serialize()',
                                         'success'=>'function(data) {

                                             if(data.status=="success"){
                                             $("#form1").remove(); 
                                             $("#alert1").remove(); 
                                            }
                                             else{
                                            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                            $("#"+key+"_em_").text(val);                                                    
                                            $("#"+key+"_em_").hide();
                                            $("#"+key+"_em_").text(val);                                                    
                                            $("#"+key+"_em_").show();
                                            });
                                        }       
                                    }',  
                                     ),array('id'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn btn-primary'));
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is not the actual answer to your question but hope this helps you)

put this failure function after success to find out whats wrong?

```
error: function(data) { // 500 Status Header
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data.errors, function(index, value) {
            alert(value);
        });
    },
```

Comment: thanks for reply but at m code  i can include (info_form . php)  but when i get form  and click submit  go to (site/add_main_info) and echo json event Success or fail   not make ajax code

Answer (score 0):

In Yii we had AjaxButton()  which give you all fetchers of Ajax , I created  example to help you , in this example dataType is JSON

View :

```
 <?php
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app','Create') : Yii::t('app','Save'),$model->isNewRecord ? array('questions/create') : array(Yii::app()->controller->id . '/update?id=' . $model->q_id),array(
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>'function(data) {
                     $("#AjaxLoader").hide();
                    if(data.status=="success"){

                   // do something here 

                    }
                    else{
// print error messages 
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $("#questions-form #"+key+"_em_").text(val);
                            $("#questions-form #"+key+"_em_").show();

                        });
                    }
                }',
            'beforeSend'=>'function(){
    $("#AjaxLoader").show();
}'
            ),array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'id'=>'slink-btn'.uniqid()));
        ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
...
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $this->pageTitle = Yii::t('app','create');
        $model=new Questions;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Questions']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Questions'];
            $model->user_id=uid();
            if ($model->validate()) {
                $model->save(false);

                echo CJSON::encode(array('status' => 'success'));
                Yii::app()->end();
            } else {
                $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
                if ($error != '[]')
                    echo $error;
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }

        if (Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest())
            echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model' => $model), true, true); //This will bring out the view along with its script.

        echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model' => $model), true, true); //This will bring out the view along with its script.
    }
...
```

?>

For your question you need to edit your form to be like this :

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'events-serach-form',
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//index.php/site/search'),
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal SearchForm'),
    )); ?>
```

References :

http://www.codexamples.com/90/chtml-ajaxsubmitbutton/

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml

Comment: i create my ajax form with ajax submit button and it works good at same page  .. when i want to generate it by jquery .. i isolated it in another page and called it by ajax ..  when i click to my button i get this form but don't work  like at same page  .. i hope u understand mr

Comment: @Ali Adel try to add controller path to your form :
 'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//index.php/site/search'), 
complete read my answer .

Comment: My OUTPUT  in White PAGE {"FreeMainInfo_first_name":["First Name cannot be blank."],"FreeMainInfo_last_name":["Last Name cannot be blank."],"FreeMainInfo_address":["Address cannot be blank."],"FreeMainInfo_city":["City cannot be blank."],"FreeMainInfo_state":["State cannot be blank."],"FreeMainInfo_post_code":["Post Code cannot be blank."]}

Comment: @Ali Adel Very Good so your first problem was solved , you need to stop validate  or use scenario.

Comment: my controller     public function actionAdd_main_info()
 {
$model_info=new FreeMainInfo;
$user=Yii::app()->session['user_id'] ; 
   if(isset($_POST['FreeMainInfo']))  
 {
  $model_info->attributes=$_POST['FreeMainInfo'];
  if($model_info->validate())
{
    $model_info->full=1;
    $model_info->reg_id=$user;
  
          $model_info->save();
    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'success' ));
    Yii::app()->end();
    
  }
   else
   {
          $error = CActiveForm::validate($model_info);
          if($error!='[]')
          echo $error;
          Yii::app()->end();
          }   
 }
 }